# ASP.Net MVC 3: Routing URLs result in 404 when I move from local to dev server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have a simple home and game controller set up as so:

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}



public class GameController : BaseController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult New(int level = 1)
    {
        ...
    }

    public ActionResult FlipCard(int row, int column,Guid nonce)
    {
        ...
    }

    [OutputCache(Duration=Constants.CACHE_IMAGE_EXPIRATION_SECONDS)]
    public FileResult Image (Guid imageId)
    {
        ...
    }

    public ActionResult Finish()
    {
        ...
    }

}
```

I have routing set up as such in Global.asax.cs:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    ...

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

When I run the site using IIS Express; I can access http://localhost/ just fine and see the Html in my Home/Index view; as well as use actions on the game controller.

When I run the site from a virtual directory in IIS locally; I can see the same view at http://localhost/site/; and can use game controller actions here as well.

However, when I deploy to our development server in a virtual directory set up as a .Net 4 app and load up http://dev/site/; I can't see the home/index view. Instead, I just get a directory listing 
of all the files in the site root sub directory. Game controller actions aren't accessible as well. Accessing any of the site's URLs results in a 404.

Google'd around for this issue; found a few solutions and tried them all; none of them seem to work.

Some notes

- I do have MVC3 assemblies deployed to the local bin folder
- The app pool for the site on all servers is .Net 4.0.
- I built a test web form which displays the Application's root directory(Server.MapPath("~")) to confirm that the virtual directory was configured as a web app. I deployed it to http://*/site/test.aspx,
  the results were as expected:

  - Local: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\site
  - Dev: e:\inetpub\wwwroot\site

I'm stumped as to what the issue is. Any ideas? Any constructive input is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,Frank

Answer (score 0):

Is IIS set to hand off all requests to the .net handlers via a wildcard mapping? If not then .net will never see the request in order to process the route.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/508/wildcard-script-mapping-and-iis-integrated-pipeline/